# "undefined reference to" when running make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

[core.c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sP7m.png)

i dont know why I get so many undefined references in core.c, but i think i've linked everything and there is no typo.

this is my Makefile:
[Makefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaYIO.png)

For example, createHashtable() is in hashtable_debugger, and i've alraedy linked it:
[hashtable_debugger.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qFis.png)

Comment: Please [do not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), thanks.

Comment: Please do not post images and do not post just links. SO questions seeking debugging help must provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) within the post itself.

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: *i've alraedy linked it*. No you haven't. The log and Makefile clearly shows it is not linked. For example, where in your makefile do you use `hashtable_debugger.o`? The thing that needs to be linked is the object file and not the header as you seem to be implying.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether you link the hashtable_debugger object. I only see debug.o memory.o and core.o as input to the linker

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Please don't post comments as answers. And until you can post comments then please be patience.

Comment: thanks! i think i misunderstood the concept of Makefile, it's solved now!